# What are my options to work from multiple rooms? Syncing? Thin Client? VNC?

Tags: networking, vnc

I'm currently using a stationary PC in our living room. Now I'm building a hobby-room where I want to be able to work as well (=accessing all my data and programs). What would be the best approach for this? Buying a second PC and keeping my home folder in sync? Some "thin client" that can access my main computer? Using some sort of remot desktop/VNC? Any other method I don't know about?

My current situation:

- Multimedia computer running Kubuntu 20.04
- Wired 100Mbps connection in both rooms
- Want to use it for coding, browsing but also some light video editing, so latency shouldn't be to high.
- Would prefer a solution without a dedicated server, so I don't need a third machine in my home.
- Don't want to buy a laptop, because I like the ability to upgrade :-)

Answer (score 0):

My home ubuntu setup comprises two PCs connected to a data switch which itself is connected to a 4G router which gives access to the internet. Both machines are connected to the data switch by Ethernet cable.

Also connected to the data switch is a NAS which provides common file storage through a SAMBA share. Additionally, I use a free Dropbox account where files can be stored for online access off site accessible from either machine. Using either Dropbox (which automatically syncs with the Dropbox folder in the Home directory on both machines) or the NAS, I can easily transfer files between the two PCs when necessary.

This setup has worked successfully now for a number of years and should be fairly easy for you to set up given the infrastructure you have already put in place.